# Is there proposal for introducing reactive programming constructs in Java/JakartaEE?

Tags: jakarta-ee, project-reactor

Currently, Flux and Mono are specified by the Project Reactor. Is there a proposal of bringing reactive programming constructs in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 9 has introduced the [Flow API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Flow.html), which enables us to adopt Reactive Programming using just the JDK. However, Flow API is just an API, does not implement the Reactive specification.

Brian Goetz, one of the architects of the Java language, said:
"*I think Project Loom is going to kill Reactive Programming*" ([interview link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9si7gK94gLo&t=1156s))

That being said, I think, the need for additional libraries such as Project Reactor or RxJava will be necessary.

Comment: Is Project Loom included in Spring Boot 3?